# -moz-document element CSS not getting rendered

Tags: html, css, firefox

I've this specific CSS code for Firefox browsers.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix(){
.bill-tab-fixed-width{
    width:104.5px;
 }
}
```

But firefox does not render this value. It instead render the style that I've defined for other browsers! When I inspect the element the value I've defined is strike through. Am I doing this wrong? Please help!

Firefox version 19.0.2

Thank you.

Comment: Is this rule after the other rules? Try adding `!important`temporarily - does that help?

Comment: When I add !important it doesn't even shot with the strike through. it's no after the other rules! but it's before the other rule which applies to the same element for other browsers!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its basically being overwritten by the other rules. Either move this block below the other rules in the stylesheet or add `!important` to force it to use this style.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix(){
.bill-tab-fixed-width{
    width:104.5px !important;
 }
}
```

**Note:** defining pixel values as a decimal is probably not a good idea. It is impossible for a screen to use half of a pixel and browsers can tend to round slightly differently.

Comment: I din't down vote your answer! :O it's the perfect answer for my situation.

Comment: @jimjimmy1995 It's quite possible for a screen to use "half a pixel".  These are CSS pixels, not device pixels.  For example, on any "retina" Mac or iPad or whatnot a single CSS px is two screen pixels wide by two screen pixels tall.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky Yes but not all screens can. You are targeting a relatively small portion of people there.

Comment: True, but fwiw a growing one.  Furthermore, even on low-res screens browsers can do subpixel layout, though you're right that some of them don't do it very well.